# Closed-form expression for $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(\frac{(ln(4n+3))^k}{4n+3}-\frac{(ln(4n+5))^k}{4n+5}),$ where $k$ is a positive integer

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

1. I recently came across this infinite series:
   $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(\ln(4n+3))^2}{4n+3}-\frac{(\ln(4n+5))^2}{4n+5}\right)$$
   Is it possible to express the series in closed-form? If so, how should I go about it?
2. More generally, how could one express the following infinite series in closed form?
   $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(\ln(4n+3))^k}{4n+3}-\frac{(\ln(4n+5))^k}{4n+5}\right),$$
   where $k$ is a positive integer.

For anyone who would like more context, I came across the first series in my solution to the following question: Choose $x$, $y$, $z$, and $w$ from $(0,1)$. Find the probability that $\dfrac{x}{yzw}$ rounds to an even number

Thank you!

Comment: These are higher derivatives of the Dirichlet beta function at $1$. Just like higher derivatives of $(s-1)\zeta(s)$, one has to invoke [Stieltjes-related constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) for this.